# Nested list with TWIG in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

i have in database

```
Category:
id | name
1  | first
2  | second
etc
```

and:

```
News:
id | category | name
1  | 1        | one
2  | 2        | two
3  | 1        | three
4  | 2        | four
5  | 2        | five
```

ETC.

how is the best method for show this in TWIG?

```
FIRST
- one
- three
SECOND
- two
- four
- five
```

etc.

in Symfony 1.4 i can use get data from template PHP, but in Symfony 2 i must get all data in controllor, but how?

Comment: Is there a relation defined between the two models?

Comment: yes, of course. this is only simply example. i would like learn this

Answer (score 3):

So you have a working relation between Category and News, it is working straightforward.

```
// Class Category
/**
 * Relation to News
 * 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="News", mappedBy="news")
 */
private $news;
public function getNews()
{
    return $this->news;
}
```

So you pass the category object(s) from controller to your template, and TWIG converts the "category.news" towards the Category->getNews() function.

```
{% for newsitem in category.news %}
    <p>{{ newsitem.id }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

You may find further information on this "variable/function handling": http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using Sf2 (yet) so I can't give you exactly what you need, but it should be similar to this:

- in your controller, get all categories, inner joining with the relation to news (to make sure a single query is used to get all the data needed)
- in your template, do a `for` on the categories
- in that loop, do a `for` on the current category's relation to news

Comment: i know, but how make "in that loop, do a for on the current category's relation to news " in TWIG ?

Comment: to @MartinSowning you may take a look at my answer for your further question